# Selecting count of zero while grouping by column

Tags: mysql, database, count, group-by

I have a jobs table, and am trying to get a count of jobs for different time frames.  My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count', 
       WEEK(j.created_at) AS 'week',
       MONTH(j.created_at) AS 'month', 
       YEAR(j.created_at) AS 'year', 
       DATE_FORMAT(j.created_at, '%y') AS 'short_year'
FROM jobs j WHERE j.state <> 'draft' 
            AND created_at > '2010-06-21'
            AND created_at < '2010-08-01'
GROUP BY WEEK(j.created_at)
ORDER BY WEEK(j.created_at)
```

To change my timeframe, I simply change the `GROUP BY` from `WEEK` to `MONTH`, and I get counts by month instead of week.

The problem is that I am not getting empty rows for weeks with 0 jobs.  My result set from the query above is:

```
count week  month  year short_year
    3   25      6  2010         10
    2   26      6  2010         10
    2   27      7  2010         10 
    1   28      7  2010         10
    3   30      7  2010         10
```

You'll notice that there is no data for week 29, which should be a row with count(0).  Is there any way to get that 0 count row, while maintaining the flexibility of changing my grouping between `WEEK` and `MONTH`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an auxiliary calendar table containing every date and outer join onto that (the below may need tweaking if `created_at` has a time component)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count', 
       WEEK(c.date) AS 'week',
       MONTH(c.date) AS 'month', 
       YEAR(c.date) AS 'year', 
       DATE_FORMAT(c.date, '%y') AS 'short_year'
FROM calendar c
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs j ON j.created_at = c.date
            AND j.state <> 'draft' 
WHERE c.date > '2010-06-21'
            AND c.date < '2010-08-01'
GROUP BY WEEK(c.date)
ORDER BY WEEK(c.date)
```

Comment: We don't have a calendar table with data like that, and creating one would require significant changes to the data structure of the app that I don't have time to implement. If I change all your `c.date` to `c.created_at`, and use `jobs` instead of `calendar`, it returns the same dataset as my original query.

Comment: You need to **create** the auxiliary calendar table first.

Comment: See my modified comment above.  That would rerquire a significant amount of changes to the Rails application serving this data, and I don't have time to implement those changes.

Comment: Well there's nothing in `SQL` that will help you add in the missing rows if they are not in the data.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your answer.  Your calendar table has a record for every day, not just the days that jobs were created, correct?

Comment: @Mike - Yes. One record for each day which might feasibly ever be included in the query.

Comment: I've implemented the calendar, but there is still a problem.  I'm now getting a result that says there are 7 results for the week of 29, when the count was previously 0.  I'm using your exact query from above.

Comment: @Mike - Ah use `COUNT(j.created_at)` instead of `*`

Comment: Doing that returns a count of 0 for ALL rows.  Oh the humanity.

Comment: Does `created_at` have a time component meaning that the exact equality join won't work?

Comment: Indeed it does.  Is there a MySQL function that can fix this issue?

Comment: Ahh, the DATE() function!  Thanks for all the help and time, it appears to be working now!

Comment: You might find it improves performance to use `j.created_at >= c.date and j.created_at < DATE_ADD(c.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);` Alternatively it might not!