# MySQL get daily counts over an interval

Tags: mysql, date, count, intervals

How can I get the number of records over a date interval, including dates with no records?

For example I have the following table:

```
   DATE    | INSERTID  
2011-12-10 |    1  
2011-12-10 |    2  
2011-12-12 |    3  
2011-12-13 |    4  
2011-12-15 |    5  
2011-12-15 |    6
```

and the result to be:

```
   DATE    | COUNT(INSERTID)  
2011-12-10 |   2  
2011-12-11 |   0  
2011-12-12 |   1  
2011-12-13 |   1  
2011-12-14 |   0  
2011-12-15 |   2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting count of zero while grouping by column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824686/selecting-count-of-zero-while-grouping-by-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're going to want to start by generating your list of days, then left join to your object table, grouping on date and doing a count() on the object table.  There's [already an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2157282/65131) that covers generating the dates, from the looks of it.